# df.replace(np,nan) adding extra rows out of data frame length

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge

I have data in txt file and the result of the `count_row = df1.shape[0]` is `13248`.

I have derived column `['Seasonality']`  from another `df_all` dataframe  which is in total `2246` rows using the `merger` :

```
df2= pd.merge(df1,df_all[['PC9','Seasonality']], on='PC9', how='left')
```

In column `['Seasonality']`  I have some `NAN` what I want to replace with `NIS` and Im doing this  with code:

```
df2['Seasonality']=df2['Seasonality'].replace(np.nan,'NIS')
```

when I finally doing  `df2.to_csv`

Desired out come should be `13248` rows in total but only `['Seasonality']`  column goes until `14865` row with NIS filled in. Not sure what Im doing wrong

Comment: Are all of your rows in df_all exact matches to df1? Do `print(len(df2))` after you do the merge.

Comment: yes it gives me that number `14864`. What could be a reason? in `df_all` there might be some that I dont have a match in `df1`

Comment: let's say in your `df1['PC9']` there is a value of `123`. If your `df_all['PC9']` contains two `123`, then what happens in `merge` is that each of the two `123` from `df_all` will be merged to `df1`, resulting in two rows in your `df2`. so the number of rows of `df2` becomes 1 row more than `df1`.

Comment: If `df_all['PC9']` doesn't contain repeated values, you can safely say that the number of rows won't grow. If it grows, your `df_all['PC9']` contains repeated values. Growing isn't wrong.

Comment: but when I export it to csv after `merge` I have only 13248 rows in the file but if i `print(len(df2))` after `merge` it shows extra rows. is not it weird? How am I suppose to fix this?

Comment: Correction on my comment: `nrow(df2)` not `print(len(df2))`. I was in python mindset.